# Why h2 not found a column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have following problem

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Kolumna
> "CREATED_AT" nie istnieje Column "CREATED_AT" not found; SQL
> statement: insert into taco (id, created_at, name) values (null, ?, ?)
> [42122-200]

but in h2 console the column is present

[image]

i have following schema.sql code

```
create table if not exists Taco(
id identity,
name varchar(50) not null,
createdAt timestamp not null
);
```

and domain

```
package my.taco.models;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
public class Taco {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=5,message = "Nazwa musi składać się z przynajmniej pięciu znaków")
    private String name;

    private Date createdAt;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Ingredient.class)
    @Size(min=1,message = "Musisz wybrac przynajmniej jeden składnik")
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients;

    @PrePersist
    void createdAt(){
        this.createdAt=new Date();
    }
}
```

so what`s wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default column name guessed by Hibernate (based on the attribute name) is `CREATED_AT` but yours is `CREATEDAT`

You can either rename the column in your database (recommended because it is more standard) or you can specify the column name to Hibernate like this :

```
@Column(name="CREATEDAT")
private Date createdAt;
```